# Does reading/writing different elements of array lead to data race conditions in multithreading loop in Julia

Tags: multithreading, julia

I am trying to build an API for a stochastic mortality model in Julia. During the fitting process for this model, multiple optimization problems need to be solved. I don't think all of the mathematical details of the model are necessary but suffice it to say that there are parameters to be estimated for each age and time period (years) in the model.

The optimization problem is done on a per-period basis i.e. each year has its own objective function `f_obj_t(kt)` where `kt` is the current year's parameter, and it never uses/reads any other years' parameters. It does rely on all of the age parameters however these do not change as a result of the optimization process as it is only done for the time-based parameters.

Since the optimization can be parallelized I have implemented it using channels and splitting the data needed for each objective function. A sample of this is given below.

```
function adjust_BMS!(out::Channel, mdf::DataFrame)
    dfs_byyear = Dict()
    years = unique(mdf.Year)
    for y in years
        dfs_byyear[y] = @subset(mdf, :Year .== y)
    end

    @threads for year in years
        df = dfs_byyear[year]
        k0 = df.Kappa[1]

        println("Optimising [BMS] $year on Thread $(threadid())")
        opt_result = optimize(k -> calculcate_deviance!(k, df), gen_gradient_func(df), [k0])
        put!(out, (Year=year, Kappa=opt_result.minimizer[1]))
    end
end
```

What I am wondering is if there is a more efficient way to do this, perhaps just forgoing the channels and letting the optimization functions directly interact with the raw data frame. My thinking is that since optimizations will never read/write data that doesn't belong to the year currently being optimized there is little room for data race conditions. However, I am incredibly unfamiliar with multithreading so I am not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are sure that each thread reads/writes a different part of memory (I guess in your code this is identified by year) than you can just create a `Vector` of some data indexed by years and just reach it directly. In your code Channel seems to unnecessary complicate things.